# Getting a webservice to use a certificate

Tags: delphi, iis, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

the title might be a bit off but I really didnt know how to put it in a title.

The situation is as follows.

There are 3 applications.
1. A stand alone windows application
2. A webservice that runs in IIS
3. A REST server

Our users work with the windows application(1).
The REST server only allows calls by using our client certificate, we want to prevent that just anyone can do calls so we added another layer by letting people do a call to our webservice (2) which then does the call to the REST server(3).

We have 2 versions of this webservice, one is standalone, the other is running in IIS. When we use the standalone version it all works fine, but when we use the IIS version we get an error

**REST Request failed: Unspecified certificate from client.**

I assume that the client certificate that was installed is not accessible by IIS and i've been searching on google without result so far.

Basicly I am looking for a way to install the certificate in such a way that the webservice will use this certificate when making the call to the REST server.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.
The windows standalone application is made with Delphi, so is the webservice.
If there is additional information required please let me know and I will provide what I can.

Thanks in advance

**Q:** By @mjn "Can you provide more details about how your IIS application is coded? (coded in Delphi? which HTTP client library? How does the actual HTTP request code like like?)"
**A:** Yes it's coded in Delphi, for the request I used a class that uses the delphi component TRestClient

Example of a request:
[image]

Call to the request:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details about how your IIS application is coded? (coded in Delphi? which HTTP client library? How does the actual HTTP request code like like?)

Comment: @mjn I added some additional information, is the added information sufficient? If not, please let me know. Could head into a chat if you'd prefer that.

Comment: I guess the IIS does not have anything to do with the HTTP request, your code which runs within the IIS DLL must add the certificate by itself. In other words: if the standalone application works (and provides the certificate with the request), you must use basically the same code in the IIS DLL to make it work.

Comment: Well that is the weird part. The standalone version and the IIS DLL use the same codebase. So its identical, yet it works for the former but not for the latter

Comment: The code which you have shown does not set a client certificate, so it is not possible to see any potential errors. If you modify the standalone service so that it does not send a client certificate, do you get the same error message?

Comment: I will try that out as soon as I can, I have a bunch of meetings planned for today so might not get to it until tomorrow

Comment: I read that the certifactes must be installed in the certificate store, and then the TRESTClient will automagically pick them from there. Maybe for the IIS the certificates are 'invisible' (bad store location)

Comment: That is what happend for the standalone. I also found out that I was missing the OnNeedClientCertificate event. So I have added that, now it still works for the standalone version but not the isapi version. I did find out that in System.Net.HTTPClient.Win there is an event/function DoGetClientCertificates. 
It will get the CertStore which will result in nil when I run the ISAPI version of the webservice.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your ISAPI dll runs with another user (IIS Appool user). If you Install the certificate for the computer account it should work.